# How to insert data to Django database from python file periodically

Tags: python, django, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

can anyone please help me

I have created a model, like so

```
class TickerOHLC(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    open = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    low = models.FloatField()
    high = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date), str(self.open)
```

and I can insert data into the database by uploading a file in the admin panel using import-export, like so

[Screenshot of admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppZ3o.png)

Here are the admin.py content

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(Task, TickerOHLC)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

How can I import data to the database from a .py file? I have tried this

```
from tasks.models import TickerOHLC #This import gives an error: No module named 'tasks'
dataframe = generateDataframe() #function that returns a dataframe

datas = [
    TickerOHLC(
        date = dataframe.iloc[row]['Date'],
        open = dataframe.iloc[row]['Open'],
        close = dataframe.iloc[row]['Close'],
        low = dataframe.iloc[row]['Low'],
        high = dataframe.iloc[row]['High'],
        volume = dataframe.iloc[row]['Volume'],
    )
    for row in dataframe.iterrows()
]
TickerOHLC.objects.bulk_create(datas)
```

Here are my folder structure

[Screenshot of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4UDf.png)

I am new to Django and I don't even know if my approach is possible

My goal is to be able to run a script periodically that inserts into the database

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Where is the import file located in your project?  And how are you executing it?

Comment: As for the *periodic task* part of your question, I would recommend starting with **[`django-background-tasks`](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to import models.py which is at "tasks/models.py" to "tasks/jobs/generateOHLC.py". I execute it by running the generateOHLC.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` because your project directory wasn't included in the `PATH` variable, which Django normally does for you via the `python3 manage.py` command.

If you were to set the `PATH` variable manually, you would end up getting an `ImproperlyConfigured` error because your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable was not set (again, Django normally does this for you).

Instead of trying to configure everything outside of django, it's **much** easier to use the `python3 manage.py` utility.

In your case, the the easiest fix is to put this script in a custom **[`Management Command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)**, in the directory `tasks/management/commands/my_command.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from tasks.models import TickerOHLC

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        dataframe = generateDataframe()
        
        datas = [
            TickerOHLC(
                date = dataframe.iloc[row]['Date'],
                open = dataframe.iloc[row]['Open'],
                close = dataframe.iloc[row]['Close'],
                low = dataframe.iloc[row]['Low'],
                high = dataframe.iloc[row]['High'],
                volume = dataframe.iloc[row]['Volume'],
            )
            for row in dataframe.iterrows()
        ]
        TickerOHLC.objects.bulk_create(datas)
```

Now to execute this command, simply call `python3 manage.py my_command`, and Django will configure everything for you.

This good for testing and for tasks you typically use during development, but isn't suitable for *periodic tasks* that you mentioned in your question.  For that I would recommend starting with **[`django-background-tasks`](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. Now all I gotta do is schedule it

Answer (score 0):

You need an empty `__init__.py` file in every folder so that python is able to import modules. the parent directory doesn't have an `__init__.py` file and that's why the import is failing.

Secondly, for periodic tasks, you should look into [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have created an empty __init__.py file in the "jobs" folder and tried to import models with "from tasks.models import TickerOHLC"  and I still get the same error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the `__init__.py` in all your folders, i think it's missing in the `tasks` parent directory too.

Comment: there is already an `__init__.py` file in the tasks folder

Comment: `manage.py` is at the root folder (can be seen in the folder structure screenshot for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing this code outside of Django, please add below two lines of code at the beginning.

```
import django
django.setup()
```

If you are planning to schedule automatic execution of the file, it is better to set up [Job Scheduling using django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jobs_scheduling.html).
In that case above 2 lines of code are not required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand what you mean by "outside of Django" but I tried anyway and got this error message `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`. My file is named generateOHLC.py in the jobs folder (as seen in the folder structure screenshot)

Comment: update: added `from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()` but got the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'`